# Getting a ListView to work when grabbing data from a mySQL server

Tags: android, mysql, database, json, listview

As the title says, I have a mySQL database that has data on it. I want my android app to retrieve that data and insert it into a ListView. I don't think I'm doing it correctly because my current code; although not producing any errors, doesn't work. Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/sZy5dAzS

I'd just like to point out that when I insert that data into a TextView it shows up on my app just fine. So it must be that I'm doing something wrong with my ListView. I just don't know what.

Just to make it easier to read these are the parts of my ListView:

At the top of my code

```
List<String> nameData = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The for loop for my JSON Parsing:

```
            try {
                jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data = null;
                currentList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);



                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    nameData.add(drivername = json_data.getString("Driver_full_name"));
                    nameData.add(drivesfor = json_data.getString("Drives_for"));

                }
```

I do have a catch here as you can see in the pastebin link, just haven't posted it.

and the onPostExecute

```
protected void onPostExecute(String output){

        currentList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>    (CurrentSeasonDrivers.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, nameData));
        Toast.makeText(CurrentSeasonDrivers, "DONE!",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Just to reiterate; a TextView works fine when pulling the data so the rest of the code is correct.

Really appreciate any help given. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the exact problem is in your code but I have a feeling it has to do with your adapter. I have suggestion on a way to do it that should work and that is better and more flexible which is basically creating your own adapter.

First make a small Driver class which will be used as the source of data

```
public class DriverItem {

    private String name;
    private String driversFor;

    public DriverItem(String n, String d) {
        super();
        this.name = n;
        this.driversFor = d;
    }

    // Getter and setter methods for all the fields.
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDriversFor() {
        return driversFor;
    }
```

}

**Now create the adapter which will be used for creating the views**

```
public class DriverListItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<DriverItem> listDriverItem;
    private Context context;

    public DriverListItemAdapter(Context ctx, List<DriverItem> list)
    {
        context = ctx;
        listDriverItem = list;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listDriverItem.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listDriverItem.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DriverItem driver = listDriverItem.get(position);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
        TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        name.setText(driver.getName());

        return convertView
    }
}
```

**Now you need the view which will be used to display each listview row**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**And now in your code you simply create the arraylist of drivers, create an adapter out of that, and set that adapter on your listview.**

```
DriverListItemAdapter adapter;
ListView currentList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
ArrayList<DriverItem> listOfDriverListItem;

for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
            jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);        
            listOfDriverListItem.add(newDriverItem(jObj.getString("Driver_full_name"),jObj.getString("Drives_for")));
        }

adapter = new DriverListItemAdapter(this, listOfDriverListItem);
currentList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You should be able to just copy paste the all of these things into their own classes and it should work.. and replace your listview code with the one I gave at the bottom.. 
This should work, let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm just wondering. Don't I have to put anything in the onPostExecute? Otherwise nothing will display on the applications page.

Anyway I ran the code and got a force close. Here is the logcat: http://pastebin.com/Z4Svaw6t

Comment: can you paste your new code in paste bin and link it please. Also yes it would be a good idea to do any actual view updating/setting inside a postExecute instead of the actual background task.. your task should get the JSON and the post execute should use the JSON to set views

Comment: One issue I see is that in your getView you are doing

convertView = inflater.inflate(R.id.list, null);

You have to inflate the layout file that contains the R.id.DriverName textbox. What did you call that layout? The one I provided with my answer - The LinearLayout with the txtName textview

Comment: Ah ok, I named it currentseasons_drivers. Here is my updated code, still getting the force close error though. updated code: http://pastebin.com/z6gc8QNf

logcat: http://pastebin.com/mMm9djA7

There's not another way to do it is there? Maybe not using a ListView at all. All I want to do is present the data in two columns. Maybe two separate textviews for each column then format it in the XML layout. Although the last time I used the TextView it did it with all the curly brackets and what not showing.

Comment: That is the same layout that you are using for your activity isn't it? I see at the top you have `setContentView(R.layout.currentseason_drivers);`
I am not sure if you can inflate the same layout inside a listview that the listview is located in...

Can you create a new layout file and try with that..

What the inflating part does is that it uses that view for each row in your listview

Comment: nope same, a force close and the logcat is identical to the last. I called the layout testlayout. Relative with just the textview in it. 

I edited my post above.

Comment: Without being on your computer I can't go through it step by step and find the problem then.. In response to what you said I guess you could just have a loop that does the following for both name and drives_for .. `txtName.setText(txtName.getText() + "\n" + driverName);` .. Basicaly keep appending the text to it

and populate the entire textview like that..

make sure when you create it you set it as multi line textview though

Comment: Don't mean to be a pain but how would i set it as a multi-line TextView?

Comment: try the maxLines and lines attributes of your textview in your XML layout file.. for example

    `android:maxLines="5"` and
    `android:lines="5">`

Please up vote my answer for effort at least :D